# Fetching image from php web service using JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I want to fetch images from the php web service in my javascript code using json. The alert in the for loop returns "undefined". Please help with your suggestions.

```
<script>
    var menu_category;
    var menu_id = [];
    var menu_title = [];
    var menu_img = [];
    "use strict";

    function jsonp(url) {
        alert("JSONP URL");
        var head = document.head;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("src", url);
        head.appendChild(script);
        head.removeChild(script);
    }

    function jsondata(data) {
        alert("JSONdata");
        var parsedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        var parsed_data = parsedata["main Category"];
        for (var i = 1; i <= parsed_data.length; i++) {
            alert("FOR");
            menu_id[i] = parsed_data.mcatid;
            alert(menu_id[i]);
        }
    }
    jsonp("http://remoteaddress/maincategory.php?callback=jsondata");
</script>
```

Comment: can you post the value/structure of the variable 'parsed_data'

Comment: "parsed_data" returns the following structure,                   [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]         There are 4 images on the server to be fetched.

Comment: see what this statement returns console.log(parsed_data)

Comment: It doesn't return anything.

Comment: I meant what does it display in the console?

Comment: It doesn't display anything... and just by trial error i got my image.. in the hard coded part for <img src="  "> , i entered the URL for image. and it worked. But my confusion now is, is it needed to parse an image which I was trying since morning?

Comment: if its a valid json then you don't need to...but if your response is in a string format then you need JSON.parse to get a valid JSON object and then extract the desired data.